# Assign unique id based on combination in sql

Tags: sql

The data looks like this:

[image]

Need to assign id based on the combination of 2 columns and get the id of each value in 2 columns

[image]

final output should look like:

[image]

I tried with

```
WITH RNS AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn
  FROM test
),
IDS AS (
  SELECT t1.coLA, t1.colB, t1.rn, MIN(COALESCE(t2.rn, t1.rn)) AS id
  FROM RNS t1
  LEFT JOIN RNS t2 ON t1.rn > t2.rn
    AND (t1.colA = t2.colA OR t1.colA = t2.colB OR
         t1.colB = t2.colA OR t1.colB = t2.colB)
  GROUP BY t1.coLA, t1.colB, t1.rn
  ORDER BY t1.rn
)
SELECT colA, colB, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS id
FROM IDS
ORDER BY rn
```

but not working as expected

Comment: What does this have to do with Python? Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? How your id should be defined?

Answer (score 0):

Using **[RECURSIVE CTE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#recursive_keyword)** in BigQuery, you may try below query

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE test AS (
  SELECT * EXCEPT(offset)  
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT('abaaeghjc', '')) colA WITH OFFSET 
    JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT('bccdfhikl', '')) colB WITH OFFSET USING (offset)
),
IDS AS (
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY colA) id
    FROM test t1
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test t2 WHERE t1.colA = t2.colB)
   UNION ALL
  SELECT t.*, id FROM IDS i JOIN test t ON i.colB = t.colA
)
SELECT DISTINCT col, id FROM IDS, UNNEST([colA, colB]) col
 ORDER BY 1;
```

###### Query results:

```
+-----+----+
| col | id |
+-----+----+
| a   |  1 |
| b   |  1 |
| c   |  1 |
| d   |  1 |
| e   |  2 |
| f   |  2 |
| g   |  3 |
| h   |  3 |
| i   |  3 |
| j   |  4 |
| k   |  4 |
| l   |  1 |
+-----+----+
```